# Save multiple files with different names on fprintf in C

Tags: c, printf, filenames

I want to save multiple .dat files but apears the warning: "format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 3 has type ‘double *’ [-Wformat=]" and the files come out empty.

```
FILE *f1;
double hist[N];
double delta_t = 0.25;
int n_periodos = 0;
char name[100]; 
sprintf(name,"testeT%f.dat",n_periodos*delta_t);
f1 = fopen (name,"w");
fprintf(f1,"%lf",hist); //The problem is here
```

Comment: Try picking an index in `hist`, which is a pointer to an array of `doubles` (although you'd need to add something to it first).

Comment: `hist` is an array of double (e.g. `double hist[N];`) when you pass `hist` as an argument to `fprintf` it is converted to *the address of* (hint: a pointer to) the first element (e.g. `&hist[0]` which is `'double*'`).

Comment: the question is about a compile time problem. but the posted code is just a snippit!   Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem so we can help you debug it.\

Comment: OT: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror( "your error message" )` as that will print your error message AND the text reason the system thinks the function failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem in the last line is you are passing `hist` (which is an *array of double*) to `fprintf` where you have used the `%lf` conversion specifier which expects a `double` as its argument (not an *array of double*)

When you declare an array in C, on access, the array is converted to a pointer to the first element in the array [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3). (the exceptions are stated there -- when use with `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or with the unary `&` operator, or when initialized with a *string literal*) None of those apply here.

So with your declaration of:

```
double hist[N];
```

`hist` is an array of double. When you use `hist` in:

```
fprintf (f1, "%lf", hist);
```

`hist` is converted to a pointer to the first element in the array (e.g. the *address of* the first element) which has a type `'double*'`. To correct the problem, you need to *dereference* the pointer (generally done with an array by using `[element]` following the varaible, e.g.

```
fprintf (f1, "%lf", hist[0]);  /* or element 1, 2, 3, .... */
```

This will make your types consistent.

You could rewrite your code (thought it is still unclear what `N` is), to eliminate the issue and correct some other shortcomings (identified in the comments below)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC  100   /* if you need a constant, #define on (or more) */
#define NHIST  32   /* it is unclear where N came from in your code */

int main (void) {

    FILE *f1 = NULL;            /* initialize all variables and help */
    double hist[NHIST] = {0.0}; /* avoid Undefined Behavior :)       */
    double delta_t = 0.25;
    int n_periodos = 0;
    char name[MAXC] = ""; 

    /* use snprintf to protect the bounds of 'name' */
    snprintf (name, MAXC - 1, "testeT%f.dat", n_periodos*delta_t);

    f1 = fopen (name, "w");     /* call fopen */
    if (f1 == NULL) {           /* validate file is open for writing */
        perror ("fopen-name");
        return 1;
    }

    fprintf (f1, "%lf", hist[0]);
}
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: regarding: `double hist[NHIST] = {0};`  this is initializing an array of `double`s to `int` values.  Suggest: `double hist[NHIST] = {0.0};`

Comment: Fair enough, even though `{0}` is a universal initializer, there is nothing wrong with matching the type with the content of the initializer.

Answer (score 1):

When you call runtime functions it is important to check the return values to see if they were successful or not.

Another thing to keep in mind is that float and doubles are not exact values so using them as part of a file name is not good.

So check the return value

```
f1 = fopen(name, "w");
if (f1 != NULL)
{
  ...
  fclose(f1);
}
else
{
  perror(name); // or write out the error
}
```

Note also that variables declared are not necessary 0 if you declare them in a function, they can have arbitrary values so you need to initialize them

```
double hist[N] = {0};
```

When you write the hist[] to a file you cannot use fprintf like that, you should loop through the values writing them one value at a time, fprintf can't handle writing an array like you wrote.

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
  fprintf(f1, "%lf\n", hist[i]); // added \n as delimiter
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`hist` is an array of doubles (or technically a pointer, `double*`, as its passed into fprintf), but you are attempting to write a single double value to file, not an array.  You probably want something like this to write the entire array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    fprintf(f1, "%f", hist[i]);
}
```

Or just a single value:

```
fprintf(f1, "%f", hist[0]);
```

Also, in your sample code, `hist` is an uninitialized array.  What gets written to file will likely not be what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
fprintf(f1,"%lf",hist);
```

in C, a reference to the name of an array 'degrades' to the address of the first byte of the array.

Much better to use:

```
fprintf(f1,"%lf",hist[0]);
```

as that will output the contents of the first entry in the array.